# How to declare a column as SET in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

We can declare a column as SET in MySQL. like

> CREATE TABLE myset (col SET('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));

But how to declare a column as SET in Sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such type in sqlite. You probably want to go with `TEXT` instead.